# Detecting an OS dialog box using Test::WWW::Selenium, or otherwise

Tags: perl, testing, browser, selenium, dialog

I know that Selenium has no way to detect an OS dialog box, so what I'd like to know is how this can be done in Perl.  Can I drive Selenium RC using Perl up to the point of clicking a button on a page that will open a Print dialog, then detect when that dialog box has appeared somehow using non-Selenium Perl?

If you're curious the endgame here is to record how long it takes the dialog box to load.

```
my $t0 = [gettimeofday];
$sel->click_ok("id=ctl00_ctl00_printButton");
## something like 'dialog_loads_ok("print_dialog");'
my $t1 = [gettimeofday]
my $t0_t1 = tv_interval $t0, $t1;
print "Elapsed time to load print dialog: $t0_t1 minutes\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows and X11, you should be able to use [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aGuiTest) and [X11::GUITest](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/X11%3a%3aGUITest), respectively.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  Do the window functions work for print and save-as dialog boxes?